# Remove from database on click

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, database

JS file

```
"delete"  : function() {
                  calEvent.id = id;
                  id++;                  
                  //post to events.php
                  $.post("events.php?action=del&id="+calEvent.id);                

                  $calendar.weekCalendar("removeEvent", calEvent.id);
                  $dialogContent.dialog("close");
                }
```

Send ID to events.php and than in events.php handle recieve ID

```
if (!$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '')) {
    echo 'Could not connect to mysql';
    exit;
}

if (!mysql_select_db('agenda', $link)) {
    echo 'Could not select database';
    exit;
}

if ($action == 'del')
    {
        $id = $_REQUEST['id'];

        $del = "DELETE FROM meeting_rooms_calendar WHERE id=" . $id;
        $result = mysql_query($del, $link);

    }
```

Delete from database, but it not dropping my array in database. 
What do i wrong ? Im a Beginner!

Comment: If you're just starting out, then don't learn the mysql_X functions, as those are deprecated. Use mysqli (http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or PDO (http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php). Also, others will tell you this soon enough, but sanitize your inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Try to send your parameters in the next way:

```
$.post( "events.php", { action: "del", id: calEvent.id } )
   .done( function( data ) {
       $calendar.weekCalendar("removeEvent", calEvent.id);
       $dialogContent.dialog("close");
   });
```

And of course check whether `$action` is really contains `$_POST["action"]`.